# Font rendering issue with Blink based browsers in macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, webkit

Recently [Blink based browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) show unintelligible texts on some websites, it returns to the normal state when I change the font-weight manually. Never hear or saw a thing like this before. Any ideas?

I'm running a Mac mini (M2 Pro) with Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71):

- **Edge**: 122.0.2365.80
- **Chrome**: 122.0.6261.112

Edge and Chrome reads the HTML correctly:

[image]

Edge, Chrome, Safari comparison:

[image]

Edge, DevTools “Network” tab:

[image]